# how to skip unzipping a file that already exists in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, large-files, 7zip

I have a very large 7z file in google drive.
When I use Google Colab to unzip it, It took me too much time and sometimes runtime is out
so I can not unzip the whole file successfully.
How can I skip unzip a file that already exists in google colab?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code:

```
main_path = "path_to_your_dir" # Specify the path

# Check whether the specified path exists or not
if os.path.exists(main_path)== False :
  !unzip your_zip_file.zip
```